# Laravel Import Excel into DB: ErrorException Undefined array key "name"

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to use the `Maatwebsite\Excel` package to let users import a csv or excel file and it get imported into the DB.

I am new to laravel, so I am not quite sure how to troubleshoot this issue.

I keep getting the error:

> ErrorException Undefined array key "FIRST"
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/import-form

**CSV Sample Data**

```
FIRST,LAST,EMAIL,PHONE,DEPARTMENT,LOCATION
test name 1,teast last 1,test@mail.com,123-123-1231,test department,test location
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::post('/import-form', [ImportPatientController::class, 'importForm'])->name('import.file');
```

**ImportPatientController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\ImportPatientModel;
use Excel;
use App\Imports\PatientImport;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ImportPatientController extends Controller
{



  public function importUploadForm()
  {
    return view('import-form');
  }

  public function importForm(Request $request)
  {
    Excel::import(new PatientImport,$request->file2);
    return "Record are imported successfully!";
  }
}
```

**PatientImport.php (Imports Folder)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;


use App\Models\ImportPatientModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;


class PatientImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new ImportPatientModel([
            'firstName'=>$row['FIRST'],
            'lastName' => $row['LAST'],
            'email' => $row['EMAIL'],
            'phone' => $row['PHONE'],
            'department' => $row['DEPARTMENT'],
            'location' => $row['LOCATION'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**ImportPatientModel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ImportPatientModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "imported_patients";

    protected $fillable = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'phone', 'department', 'location'];



}
```

**import-form.blade.php**

````
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('import.file')}}">
          <img class="flowhealthlogoform" src="{{ url('images/flowhealthlogo.png')}}" />
          <h1> BACKUP LIS </h1>
            <!-- CROSS Site Request Forgery Protection -->
            @csrf


            <div class="form-group">
               <label>Upload Excel Sheet</label>
               <input type="file" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('file') ? 'error' : '' }}" name="file2" id="file">

               <!-- Error -->
               @if ($errors->has('file'))
               <div class="error">
                   {{ $errors->first('file') }}
               </div>
               @endif
           </div>


            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
        </form>```
````

Comment: Try `dd($row)` in your import file (before you return the model) to see what is in the array.

Comment: @jrcamatog Thanks for the tip! Never knew that you could dump an array like that!  It returned the following ```array:6 [▼
  "first" => "test name 1"
  "last" => "teast last 1"
  "email" => "test@mail.com"
  "phone" => "123-123-1231"
  "department" => "test department"
  "location" => "test location"
]```

Comment: @jrcamatog So turns out that my headers were put into the sheet in all caps... but being imported in all lowercase... I swear I tried to put the $row['FIRST'], into lowercase last night and it didnt work.. Thanks for the help <3

Comment: @jrcamatog my first thought was $row was empty but actually, it had data, I realized this thanks to your comment, laravel-excel convert heading rows to lower case and replaces spaces with underscore, in my case heading was Marketplace ID and laravel-excels converted it to marketplace_id, thas why I got this error, Thanks

Comment: Question already answerd [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782231/undefined-index-in-maatwebsite-excel.) good luck

Answer (score 4):

Array keys in PHP are **case sensitive**.

I think if you change `$row['FIRST']` to `$row['first']` the issue will be solved!

Comment: array_combine function will work with it, one array of keys and one array of values